# NFA/DFA with variable transition conditions

Tags: dfa, nfa

Good night,

Let's suppose I have a class which implements a NFA/DFA whose transitions are stored in a .NET Dictionary structure, and which takes an input word and recognizes a set of words derivable in some way from the input. Furthermore, let's suppose that the automaton is a generic template that can be applied to different words of the same length with only a re-labeling of the transition characters. What is the best way to encode the transition function in the Dictionary so that it's transitions can be re-labeled according to the input word's characters at runtime?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following implementation which takes an NFA and converts it to a DFA (and then to a graph) using a dictionary, just like yourself:

[NFA to DFA](http://www.dina.kvl.dk/~sestoft/gcsharp/GNfaToDfa.cs)

I am uncertain whether it has the dynamic relabeling capability you are seeking, but it is very well (in-line) documented, so you may get many ideas to help you with your project.

There is also a good (more recent) article on the topic of lambda transitions, but the image links of the article are no longer valid. However it does come with downloadable source code [FSAutomata.zip](http://weblogs.asp.net/nawaf/attachment/5466426.ashx) that you can examine after reading the article:

[NFA with Lambda Transition](http://weblogs.asp.net/nawaf/archive/2007/12/17/nfa-with-lambda-transition.aspx)